# How to split an image into multiple images based on white borders between them

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to split an image into multiple images, based on the white borders between them.

for example:

[image]

### output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

using Python, I don't know how to start this mission.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is there  anything else known about a given image other than is contains some images with white borders? For example, do we know that in this case the image to be subdivided contains 4 equal-sized images in a 2x2 grid configuration?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi :) We know that the image will always contain equal-sized images, but not necessarily 4. it may be 6 or 8 and so forth.. Thanks!

Comment: Do we know the grid configurate i.e. 2x3 vs 3x2 for an image with 6 subimages?

Comment: If (A) we only know that the input image contains  nx x ny equal size rectangular images separated by white space and NOTHING else then the problem is considerably more complicated that if (B( we are given the actual nx and ny for the image. Con you please clarify if you are trying to solve (A) or (B)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for the "easy" case where we know the grid configuration. I provide this solution even though I doubt this is what you were asked to do.

In your example image of the cat, if we are given the grid configuration, 2x2, we can do:

```
from PIL import Image

def subdivide(file, nx, ny):
    im = Image.open(file)
    wid, hgt = im.size # Size of input image
    w = int(wid/nx) # Width of each subimage
    h = int(hgt/ny) # Height of each subimage
    for i in range(nx):
        x1 = i*w  # Horicontal extent...
        x2 = x1+w # of subimate
        for j in range(ny):
            y1 = j*h # Certical extent...
            y2 = y1+h # of subimate
            subim = im.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))
            subim.save(f'{i}x{j}.png')

subdivide("cat.png", 2, 2)
```

The above will create these images:

[image: Upper left]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer depended on knowing the grid configuration of the input image. This solution does not.

The main challenge is to detect where the borders are and, thus, where the rectangles that contain the images are located.

To detect the borders, we'll look for (vertical and horizontal) image lines where all pixels are "white". Since the borders in the image are not really pure white, we'll use a value less than 255 as the whiteness threshold (WHITE_THRESH in the code.)

The gist of the algorithm is in the following lines of code:

```
whitespace = [np.all(gray[:,i] > WHITE_THRESH) for i in range(gray.shape[1])]
```

Here "whitespace" is a list of Booleans that looks like

```
TTTTTFFFFF...FFFFFFFFTTTTTTTFFFFFFFF...FFFFTTTTT
```

where "T" indicates the corresponding horizontal location is part of the border (white).

We are interested in the x-locations where there are transitions between T and F. The call to the function ***slices(whitespace)*** returns a list of tuples of indices

```
[(x1, x2), (x1, x2), ...]
```

where each (x1, x2) pair indicates the xmin and xmax location of images in the x-axis direction.

The slices function finds the "edges" where there are transitions between True and False using the exclusive-or operator and then returns the locations of the transitions as a list of tuples (pairs of indices).

Similar code is used to detect the vertical location of borders and images.

The complete runnable code below takes as input the OP's image "cat.png" and:

1. Extracts the sub-images into 4 PNG files "fragment-0-0.png", "fragment-0-1.png", "fragment-1-0.png" and "fragment-1-1.png".
2. Creates a (borderless) version of the original image by pasting together the above fragments.

The runnable code and resulting images follow. The program runs in about 0.25 seconds.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def slices(lst):
    """ Finds the indices where lst changes value and returns them in pairs
        lst is a list of booleans
    """
    edges = [lst[i-1] ^ lst[i] for i in range(len(lst))]
    indices = [i for i,v in enumerate(edges) if v]
    pairs = [(indices[i], indices[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(indices), 2)]
    return pairs

def extract(xx_locs, yy_locs, image, prefix="image"):
    """ Locate and save the subimages """
    data = np.asarray(image)
    for i in range(len(xx_locs)):
        x1,x2  = xx_locs[i]
        for j in range(len(yy_locs)):
            y1,y2  = yy_locs[j]
            arr = data[y1:y2, x1:x2, :]
            Image.fromarray(arr).save(f'{prefix}-{i}-{j}.png')
                                        
def assemble(xx_locs, yy_locs, prefix="image", result='composite'):
    """ Paste the subimages into a single image and save """
    wid = sum([p[1]-p[0] for p in xx_locs])
    hgt = sum([p[1]-p[0] for p in yy_locs])
    dst = Image.new('RGB', (wid, hgt))
    x = y = 0
    for i in range(len(xx_locs)):
        for j in range(len(yy_locs)):
            img = Image.open(f'{prefix}-{i}-{j}.png')
            dst.paste(img, (x,y))
            y += img.height
        x += img.width
        y = 0
    dst.save(f'{result}.png')

WHITE_THRESH = 110  # The original image borders are not actually white
image_file = 'cat.png'

image = Image.open(image_file)

# To detect the (almost) white borders, we make a grayscale version of the image
gray = np.asarray(image.convert('L'))

# Detect location of images along the x axis
whitespace = [np.all(gray[:,i] > WHITE_THRESH) for i in range(gray.shape[1])]
xx_locs = slices(whitespace)

# Detect location of images along the y axis
whitespace = [np.all(gray[i,:] > WHITE_THRESH) for i in range(gray.shape[0])]
yy_locs = slices(whitespace)

extract(xx_locs, yy_locs, image, prefix='fragment')

assemble(xx_locs, yy_locs, prefix='fragment', result='composite')
```

Individual fragments:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The composite image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. To get the best response in this community read the "welcome" page here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Note that if an answer solves your problem you, as the OP, can mark it as the "Accepted" answer.